# Can not pass HTML form data to PHP file

Tags: html

i am using WAMP and my html form is not sending data to PHP file.

My HTML file is

```
<html>
<body>
<form acton="process.php" method="POST">

Quantity: <input name ="quantity" type ="text" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my PHP file process.php is as under

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

echo $quantity;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo it should be "action" not "acton"

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake writing your HTML code. It should be `action` and not `acton`

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

Quantity: <input name ="quantity" type ="text" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```